# Different Color of agents for specific a resourcepool

Tags: anylogic

I have three different RessourcePools all from the resource unit AGV. An agent that belongs to the ResourcePool should have a special colour. This means that all created AGVs of ResourcePool 1 should have the colour green, all created AGVs of ResourcePool 2 should have the colour blue and all created AGVs of ResourcePool 3 should have the colour red. How do I get this to work?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried already? SOF works best if you avoid "how do I do X" questions and focus on "why does my solution Y not work, I already tried Z", see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow